# Typing in entry control makes text appear in editor control instead

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a xamarin forms app which has an editor and entry control below it inside a listview,

Whenever I type into the entry control the text appears in the editor control in spite of the cursor being in the entry control.

This issue occurs in Xiaomi Redmi Note4 device only, running on Android 7.0.
Xamarin Forms Version: 2.3.4.247
Xamarin.Android Version: 2.3.4.247

Is there a fix for such an issue? Thanks

[image]

This is the code:

```
 <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="0,10,0,10" >

        <Label Text="{Binding TouchPointQuestionIDSync}" x:Name="lblYesNoWithTextField" IsVisible="False"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Question}"  TextColor="Black" FontSize="17"/>

        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start" Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="Red" Padding="{Binding TemplateBorderValue}">

            <Grid HeightRequest="30" BackgroundColor="#EEEEEE" Padding="5,10,5,10">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.05*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding QuestionPaddingValue}"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding QuestionPaddingValue}"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>

                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label x:Name="lblYes" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" TextColor="Black" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Yes}" FontSize="14"/>
                <ffimageloading:CachedImage x:Name="imgRadioYesWithTextField"  Source="{Binding ImgRadioYesSrc, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" >

                    <ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>

                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_TappedYesWithTextField" Command="{Binding ParentBindingContext.cmdListRadioButtonYesTapped,Source={x:Reference dtYesNoTextFieldPage}}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                    </ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
                <Label x:Name="lblNo" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding No}" TextColor="Black" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="14"/>

                <ffimageloading:CachedImage x:Name="imgRadioNoWithTextField" Source="{Binding ImgRadioNoSrc, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalOptions="Start">
                    <ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>

                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_TappedNoWithTextField" Command="{Binding ParentBindingContext.cmdListRadioButtonNoTapped,Source={x:Reference dtYesNoTextFieldPage}}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                    </ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                </ffimageloading:CachedImage>

            </Grid>

        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout x:Name="stkEditorContainerWithTextField" IsVisible="{Binding bSetCommentBoxVisibility}" BackgroundColor="{Binding TemplateCommentBackground}" Padding="{Binding TemplateCommentBorderValue}">

            <local1:CustomEditor VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand" x:Name="CommentBoxWithTextField"  Focused="CommentBox_FocusedWithTextField" Unfocused="CommentBox_UnfocusedWithTextField"  TextColor="Black" HeightRequest="150"  FontSize="Default" Keyboard="Default" Text="{Binding CommentBoxText, Mode=TwoWay}" IsEnabled="{Binding EnableControl}" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding bSetCommentBoxVisibility}" Padding="{Binding TemplatePaddingEstimateValue}" BackgroundColor="{Binding TemplateEstimateValueBackground}">

            <local1:CustomEntry x:Name="lblEstimatedValue" Focused="txtUserWithTextField_Focused" Keyboard="Numeric" Unfocused="txtUserWithTextField_Unfocused"  Placeholder="{Binding strEVPlaceHolder}" Text="{Binding ATFEntryText, Mode=TwoWay}"  PlaceholderColor="Gray" TextColor="Black"/>
        </StackLayout>

    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: I don't believe any resolution will come of this; but do both of the controls have the `x:Name` attribute?

Comment: @Bejasc yes both have d x:Name attribute

Comment: Some code would be useful

Comment: @JonathanTwite added the custom data template code